# presentModalViewController with ARC

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I found this snippet of code to use for good transitions:

http://srooltheknife.blogspot.co.uk/2012/03/custom-transition-animation-for-modal.html

The problem is that it uses 'modal' and my program uses ARC so modal has been deprecated in iOS 6.0.

It's only two lines that use modal, so I changed them from-

```
TransitionController.m:
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
to:
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:Nil];
```

and

```
[self presentModalViewController:modalViewController animated:NO];
to:
[self presentViewController:modalViewController animated:NO completion:nil];
```

and I execute it with:

```
FirstPage.m:
@implementation FirstPage
{
    TransitionController *tran;
}

- (IBAction)StartGame:(id)sender
{

    if (! self.mainPage)
    self.mainPage = [[MainGameDisplay alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];

    [tran presentModalViewController:self.mainPage withPushDirection:kCATransitionFromBottom];
}
```

StartGame is a button. The program runs perfectly with no errors, but when I click the button nothing happens.

---

UPDATE:

```
FirstPage.h:
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "MainGameDisplay.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
#import "TransitionController.h"
@interface ViewController : Engine
{ }
- (IBAction)StartGame:(id)sender; //Action connection ID.
@property(nonatomic, readwrite) MainGameDisplay *mainPage;

FirstPage.m:
@implementation ViewController
{
    TransitionController *tran;
}
- (IBAction)StartGame:(id)sender {
    if (! self.mainPage)
    self.mainPage = [[MainGameDisplay alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    tran = [[TransitionController alloc] initWithNibName:Nil bundle:Nil];
    [tran presentModalViewController: self.mainPage withPushDirection:kCATransitionFromBottom];
}
```

- When the 'StartGame' button is clicked, the current view is pushed to
  the left by the exact same view.
- There is a slight fade/glow of the view during the transition.
- The direction used in the method is different to the direction of the transition. E.g 'kCATransitionFromBottom' would actually be the view being pushed from the left.
- Output with every button click: "Warning: Attempt to present  on  whose view is not in the window hierarchy!"

Comment: ARC and the API change have nothing to do with each other. Have you verified that `tran` is non-nil? And what is this `presentModalViewController:withPushDirection:` method you are trying to call? There's no such method in Apple's API.

Comment: @maddy Yes that was the problem, thank you. But now I have a new one. The transition is working, but the same page leaving is being transitioned back in. What could be the reason for this?

Comment: You should post an update to the code to show what you are now using.

Comment: @rdelmar Updated the new method used.

Comment: Why did you change the original extension? Just keep it as an extension (UIViewController+Transitions.h/m), import it and use  `[self presentModalViewController: self.mainPage withPushDirection:kCATransitionFromBottom];`